# Code is not working in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

iam pretty new to android,i want to know why this is not working when opening in emulator. Error shown as unfortunatley this app is not responding.My code has no syntax errors and it successfully installed on emulator.

i am calling function anim(); in MainActivity.java

```
protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();   
        functions mActivity= new functions();
        mActivity.anim();
```

and the function has written in another class file (functions.java)

```
public class functions extends MainActivity {
    public void anim()  {
    Animation animfadein =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fadein);
    Animation animfadeout =AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.fadeout);
    findViewById(R.id.imageView1).startAnimation(animfadein);
    findViewById(R.id.imageView1).startAnimation(animfadeout);
```

Comment: Look in the logs - there's pretty much bound to be an exception logged there.

Comment: I can't albe to find the logs for emulator. where to check for that?

Comment: I can't remember offhand, but I'd expect it to be in any tutorial on Android development... or just search for it.

Comment: @user3324932 : see [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) tutorial help you. also you have DDMS option in Eclipse or Android Studio to get application logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how Android works. You do not instantiate `Activities` manually, for one. You start them by using an `Intent` combined with the `startActivity()` method. Why not put the `anim()` method in your `MainActivity` class?

Comment: ok, i understand just trying to explore it different way that's why i kept anim() in different class file.So, i got a doubt every ".java" file will be treated as Activity? Eventhough i created a new Class file from menu but not new Activity?

Comment: If you have a class that extends from the `Activity` class or some subclass of it, then it will be treated as an `Activity`. I'm not sure what the second part of your comment means. Did you right-click in Eclipse and select the "New class" option?

Comment: Yea , that's what i mean i created "New Class" not "New Activity".

Comment: Eclipse is just generating some boilerplate code for you (it probably just makes the class extend `Activity` and overrides some of the basic lifecycle methods). If you make a new file from scratch and have it extend `Activity` or some subclass of it, then the class will behave as an `Activity` regardless of what IDE you use.

Comment: Ok i got your point. But when i put the `anim()` in 'MainActivity' class as you told and called with this  `MainActivity mActivity= new MainActivity();
      mActivity.anim();` still it's not working. Its working when i put code which is inside the `anim()` directly in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method (by removing anim() method).

Comment: again, you should never instantiate an `Activity` directly. If you are currently executing in `onCreate()`, that means the `Activity` already exists and you can just call the `anim()` method directly, without needing to instantiate anything. Trying reading the Android documentation on the [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) for more information.